# How to set timing information directly into the DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom

According to this link by [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes), the `data-` attribute is used for setting data in the DOM.  I want to grab the time using `new Date().getTime()` and append it to an element in the DOM.

What is the proper way to do this in JavaScript?  It is just a simple div element and I want to set an attribute called `data-time`.

Pseduo code would be:

> div_element.data-time = new Date().getTime();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are setting and getting the value using script, DOM properties are fine:

```
div_element['data-time'] = +(new Date());
```

Comment: You can only use dot notation for property names that are valid identifiers, *data-time* isn't because of the hyphen.

Answer (score 2):

If you want support in all browsers, you can use `setAttribute()` to set the time as an attribute on the DOM element:

```
div_element.setAttribute("data-time", new Date().getTime());
```

Comment: @user3294399 - For a custom property name, you can use a DOM property name to get and set or you can use `setAttribute()` and `getAttribute()`.  You just can't mix the two techniques.  If you want to emulate something that was actually in the HTML, then you should use `setAttribute()/getAttribute()`.  If not, you can use either pair.  But, a custom property set with `setAttribute()` cannot be read via direct DOM property and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `dataset` API

```
divElement.dataset.time = new Date().getTime();
```

[Support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=dataset) is not perfect though, so be aware. IE11+. If you need to support dinosaurs go with `setAttribute` way.

Comment: dataset is not supported in all the browsers.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but a note to the OP.  This requires IE 11 or later.

Comment: more concise but not as compatible as jfriends answer - http://caniuse.com/#search=dataset

Comment: dataset is a wonderful future item, but it's a waste of time as of now, because of the work around. Use something like element.setAttribute and element.getAttribute.

Comment: I'm not saying go and use it, but web developer should think in future terms I think. Even if it's not possible to use it right away. For future reference `dataset` should be mentioned as well as `setAttribute`.

Comment: @dfsq - actually, the first four words of your answer DO say: "You should use `dataset`" so you are saying to "go and use it".  Good to know about, but not yet practical to use except in browser add-ons that are only destined to run in one browser.

Comment: Because it is a property and not a method you can not use the fascade pattern to abstract its use.  But it will be useful in the future.  My guess is 2015.

Answer (score 0):

The multitude of answers for different browsers suggest the facade pattern which jQuery likes to do.